# Migrate git repository from Gitlab-CE to Gerrit - Cannot access each repository home page

Tags: git, gerrit

I had to move some of the git repositories from Gitlab-CE to Gerrit. Since both Gitlab-CE and Gerrit were setup on the same server, I simply copied the `.git` folders to `Gerrit_SETUP/git` folder.

Then I simply do a flush all cache:

```
ssh -p 29418 thats.me@localhost gerrit flush-caches --all
```

When I log into Gerrit I now see this under repositories, however when I click the repository name I get a **404** page . I can access the other links like Changes, Repository Browser. What am I missing ?

Comment: How about creating repositories in Gerrit first and then pushing or copying the necessary metadata?

Comment: Yes if I first create the repo in GIT and simply rewrite / copy over the .git folder then its fine. But was trying to figure if this was the expected behavior . Cases where you have multiple projects being copied over will not depend on having the projects first created in Gerrit

Comment: To my knowledge, Gerrit has an internal database. If the repositories are copied/created with non-Gerrit methods, Gerrit does not know their existence.